# How to prevent multiple threads manipulating instance of referenced object?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently in the process of designing and writing an application in C# using the .NET Framework that imports some data from a file. After importing the data it can be bound to a DataGridView in one or more Windows Form's to allow the user to manipulate the data before it's exported back to a file.

I want my Form(s) to remain responsive during the exportation process with the possibility of cancelling the exportation operation. I was going to create a BackgroundWorker and setup the DoWork handler to perform the export operation, so the exportation operation is carried out in a background thread. I was doing this to allow progress of the operation to be updated in the Form(s), among other reasons. I was going to pass the data into the worker to allow it to do the export.

I'm concerned however that once I start the worker and my worker is performing the exportation operation, which may be still bound to one or more DataGridViews, that my data becomes accessible to multiple threads, and that the user could update the data using the form whilst it's being exported.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the Forms referencing and messing with the data whilst it's being exported?

I do not have any code written as yet, but I've written some code below that I hope conveys what i was thinking of doing, which i'm sure is a horrible way to do it.

```
class Data : List<string>, MyInterface
{

}

class Form
{

   Data data;

  void SetData(Data data)
  {
      this.data = data;
      dataGridView.DataSource = data;
  }

  void ButtonClickHandler()
  {
     //Create a BackgroundWorker with the DoWork handler set up to
     //save/exports each item in data to a file.

  }

}
```

Comment: Um, this is basically the entire problem statement of multithreaded design as a discipline. I therefore recommend looking up various tutorials (from MS or wherever) and then coming back after that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Well I reached a conclusion that a mutex's wouldn't help. I considered a semaphore, or some way of keeping a count of what was referencing the data, and then preventing the export if the reference count wasn't zero. But then I couldn't see any sensible way to ensure the reference count was in anyway accurate.

Comment: How about disable the grid editing function (but still allow the user to browse and view) during export and reenable the function once the export routine complete?

Comment: @Tien Dinh: I had considered that. I didn't want to trust the Form. My only other idea has been force the Form to use a read-only version of the List whilst the export was taking place, resupplying the non read only version after the export.

Comment: There are literally a thousand ways to solve this - one way would be to make a copy of the data and to pass that copy to the export routine. Then, any changes made through the form won't change the copy being exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the user to modify the data you are trying to export, you have two viable options:

1. Disable the part of the UI that allows modification of the data while the export is in progress (e.g. make the `DataGridView` cells read-only) , or
2. Make a copy of the data before exporting, and export the copy, not the live data that the user is able to edit.

Other synchronization techniques would block the UI thread, which is of course a huge "no-no".